# Jsoup login fails - System Error message

Tags: java, android, authentication, jsoup

Currently, I'm doing an application where I need to login to a news website but for some reason I receive a warning and fail to login into the website at the same time.

News website: http://www.malaysiakini.com/

News website html form:
[image: News website form]

My source code:

```
 private void login(String username, String password){


    try {

        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.malaysiakini.com/")
                .data("username", "username", "password", "password", "action","//login2.mkini.net/v2/login-exchange")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        String cookie = response.cookie("JSESSIONID");



        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.malaysiakini.com/")
                .cookie("JSESSIONID", cookie)
                .get();

        Elements loginData = document.select("logindata");


        if(!loginData.isEmpty()){
            Log.d("Login Data "," Fail : " + loginData);
        }

        else
            Log.d("Login Data "," Success : " + loginData);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The warnings:

```
W/System.err: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL.    Status=405, URL=http://www.malaysiakini.com/
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
W/System.err:     at com.example.azrie.VoiceTheNews.BackgroundProcessLogin.login(BackgroundProcessLogin.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.example.azrie.VoiceTheNews.BackgroundProcessLogin.doInBackground(BackgroundProcessLogin.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.example.azrie.VoiceTheNews.BackgroundProcessLogin.doInBackground(BackgroundProcessLogin.java:20)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Edit**

I changed the method from `POST` to `GET` and also take a look at the network but still I have no idea what I'm looking for, no idea whether I'm on the right track due to me very new to this. I included some screenshot for viewing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have all the appropriate permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Thank you for replying! So far in my manifest I have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and also `INTERNET`. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You're not missing anything.. you're getting a 405 error in your request. I suggest to check your request setting and whether you can perform a log in that way...

Comment: Sorry for asking such a basic question, but how do I check my request setting ? I'm fairly new to android and java.

Comment: Wrong url for example, `http://login2.mkini.net/v2/login-exchange` is where you need to `Jsoup.connect(..` to. The simplest way to figure out the exact details of the login request is to use e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome and look at an actually working http request (open network tab, then login, then inspect the request)

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to send a `GET` request to the site in order to get cookies. The cookie that you need later on is the _cfduid cookie.  Next you have to send a `POST` request to a second URL - `http://login2.mkini.net/v2/login-exchange` with the _cfduid and some other values, as you can see here:
[image: POST PARAMETERS]

To obtain the URL, cookies, parameters and so, you can use your browser's developer tools and monitor the trafic between the browser and the server.
I've also noticed that you've tagged your question with Android tag, so you may want to use some tool that changes your browser's `user-agent` string, because the site may respond in a different way for mobiles.