# Importing editable HTML into Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets

I know how to important HTML Data into Google Sheets so that it displays, but I am trying to figure out if it is possible to also copy a web data entry form into Google Sheets, so that you can enter values, which would then be presented by the data.

I am trying to import this calculator into Google Sheets so that I can work with the real time values.

http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/ethereum-mining-calculator

Any ideas about how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to import the actual HTML form into Google Sheets. However, here is how I would do it:

1. I would open Chrome and [find the outgoing POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome) that occurs when you press the green Calculate button on that site.
2. I would use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to test and create the request and see if it works.
3. Using Google Apps Script, you can [issue HTTP requests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). I would re-construct the request being sent in Google Apps Script.
4. To make it look nicer, you can re-construct the calculator in your Google Sheet. You can recreate the calculator's input buttons as cells and then fetch those cells in your GAS code (like, hash_rate_cell.getValue()):

[image]