# Requesting parameters are not sent over API in ionic 2

Tags: api, parameters, ionic2, http-post

I am trying to send the the parameters using a post request but the parameters are not reaching to provide back the desired result and printing null as a result in console. here is my code

```js
 var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 
    let postParams = {
      acesscode: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
      productCode:'XXXXXXXXXX'
    };
    
    this.http.post("http://www.ebiebook.com/drmapi/v1/details", JSON.stringify(postParams), options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
  
}
```

and the output screen is attached, It shows API is hitting well but the parameters data is unable to reach to provide the corresponding result. Please suggest. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This print you have attached does not show what is being sent by the request, instead it shows only the response your browser received from the server.

You better take a look at this thread here to see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome) more about. You have to check the 'Headers' tab from Chrome's console -> Network.