# OpenCart product_form html-select won't pass the value to the database

Tags: php, select, opencart, html-select, dropdown

I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_POST); echo $parcel_type; 
?>
</pre>
```

Print gives: array() 
$parcel_type gives: 0

On save it won't pass the select value. Other opencart select boxes seem identical coded but do pass the value.

Anyone an idea where I'm going wrong?

**admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl**

```
<PRE>
<?php

$parcel_option = array(
'0' => 'pakket' ,
'1' => 'brievenbuspakket',
'2' => 'brievenbuspakje <20gr',
'3' => 'brievenbuspakje <50gr',
'4' => 'brievenbuspakje <100gr',
'5' => 'brievenbuspakje <250gr',
'6' => 'brievenbuspakje <2 KG',
);

?>

<div class="form-group">

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-parcel_type"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Kies verzendvorm"</span> 

<?php  
print_r($_POST); 
echo $parcel_type; ?>
</label>

<div class="col-sm-10">

<select name="parcel_type" id="input-parcel-type" class="form-control">

<?php
if (isset($data['parcel_type'])) { 
?>
<option value="" >Kies verzendvorm</option>

<?php

$parcel_type = 0; 

$parcel_text = 0; 

asort($parcel_option);

reset($parcel_option); 

foreach($parcel_option as $parcel_type => $parcel_text):
echo '<option value="'.$parcel_type.'">'.$parcel_text.'</option>'; 

endforeach;
?>

</PRE>
```

admin/controller/catalog/product.php

```
<pre>           if (isset($this->request->post['parcel_type'])) {
            $data['parcel_type'] = $this->request->post['parcel_type'];
        } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
            $data['parcel_type'] = $product_info['parcel_type'];
        } else {
            $data['parcel_type'] = '0' ;
        }   
</pre>
```

The model files edit funtion

```
<PRE>
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "',bol_ship_time = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bol_ship_time']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', product_condition = '" . (int)$data['product_condition'] . "',external_shipment = '" . (int)$data['external_shipment'] . "', parcel_type = '" . (int)$data['parcel_type'] . "',  bol_visable = '" . (int)$data['bol_visable'] . "', nextail_visable = '" . (int)$data['nextail_visable'] . "', dutch_visable = '" . (int)$data['dutch_visable'] . "', belgium_visable = '" . (int)$data['belgium_visable'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', cost = '" . (float)$data['cost'] . "', cost_amount = '" . (float)$data['cost_amount'] . "', cost_percentage = '" . (float)$data['cost_percentage'] . "', cost_additional = '" . (float)$data['cost_additional'] . "', costing_method = '" . (int)$data['costing_method'] . "', supplier_id = '" . (int)$data['supplier_id'] . "', wholesale_cost = '" . (float)$data['wholesale_cost'] . "', shipping_cost = '" . (float)$data['shipping_cost'] . "', added_shipping_cost = '" . (float)$data['added_shipping_cost'] . "', packaging_cost = '" . (float)$data['packaging_cost'] . "', handling_cost = '" . (float)$data['handling_cost'] . "',storage_cost = '" . (float)$data['storage_cost'] . "', printing_cost = '" . (float)$data['printing_cost'] . "',margin = '" . (float)$data['margin'] . "',bol_fee_cost = '" . (float)$data['bol_fee_cost'] . "', bol_cost = '" . (float)$data['bol_cost'] . "', nextail_fee_cost = '" . (float)$data['nextail_fee_cost'] . "', nextail_cost = '" . (float)$data['nextail_cost'] . "',other_cost = '" . (float)$data['other_cost'] . "',bol_price = '" . (float)$data['bol_price'] . "', nextail_price = '" . (float)$data['nextail_price'] . "', min_profit = '" . (float)$data['min_profit'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
</PRE>
```

Comment: What about the javascript function that is triggered on the click of the add-to-cart button? Can you post that?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the add to the cart button. This function is added to the admin side of the product page (product_form).  Also added some checkboxes which work fine. Only the selectbox doesn't . This is an exact copy of all the code which is used for the other html-select boxes. I couldn't find any java or JQuiry for this in the admin product_form pages. The Database field (parcel_type) is added in the model. I Thought i missed a JQuiry or something but i couldn't find that for other html-selects in the product-form.

Comment: If you look at the network activity in the browser’s developer tools when you click submit, do you see the value being sent?

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundarybU8ytNpb78nsswIE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parcel_type"

6  It is send. Base value is 0  I checked the DB. No change. Frontend No change.   Fro anyone who needs to know how to find the $_post value check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome

Comment: If i remove the (isset()) in the product.php than there is an undefined index parcel_type error.  I checked the database .. parcel_type is there.  Checked the model for typo's. Non.  The select value in the paorduct_form.tpl is there. So that should leave only an error in the controlers product.php.  I checked the array for the products 'parcel_type' => $result['parcel_type'],

Answer (score 0):

I got it working sofar with this in the product_form.tpl

```
<?php
$parcel_option = array(
''  => 'Kies verzendvorm',
'0' => 'pakket' ,
'1' => 'brievenbuspakket',
'2' => 'brievenbuspakje <20gr',
'3' => 'brievenbuspakje <50gr', 
'4' => 'brievenbuspakje <100gr',
'5' => 'brievenbuspakje <250gr',
'6' => 'brievenbuspakje <2 KG',   
);

?>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-parcel-type"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Kies verzendvorm"</span> 
<?php echo $entry_parcel_type; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="parcel_type" id="input-parcel-type" class="form-control">
<?php       

if (isset($data['parcel_type'])) { 
?>
<option value="<?php '.$parcel_type.'?>" ><?php echo  $parcel_type; ?></option>

<?php
foreach($parcel_option as $parcel_type => $parcel_text):
echo '<option value="'.$parcel_type.'">'.$parcel_text.'</option>'; 
endforeach;
?>

<?php } else { ?>
<option value="0" selected="selected"> Geen selectie - Standaard pakketkosten</option>
<?php }  ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Only thing i can't find out is how to link this code

```
<option value="<?php '.$parcel_type.'?>" ><?php echo  $parcel_type; ?>
```

to the array so it shows the parcel text that belongs to the Parcel_type.