# Chrome developer tool does Not capture a form submit in network tab, Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, forms

a simple html page,

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="abc">
        <input ... />
    </form>
</body>
```

submit the form with javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()
```

The request was indeed submitted (the server return a file as download), but I could not find any activity in network tab.

[image]

any idea? thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Firefox is working well on capturing this.
[image]

Comment: Is this html page is your popup or a normal page? are you inspecting the network for your popup page {right click on popup page>inspect>network} or for a normal page{right click on browser page>inspect>network}?

Comment: Because you create a new window with new page loaded by submit process and that clears all network history from prior window (page)

Comment: @charlietfl As seen in the photo, he has checked the preserve log option, which will not clear the console after it refreshes, right?

Comment: @Yazan W Yusuf,  it's a normal page, I simplified a bit.

Comment: Could you please give more details. This script is in a content page, right?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same content page. or run it directly in console tab.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197547/3774338

If it triggers an event to download a file, Chrome will create a new tab and this tab will be closed immediately so that you cannot capture this request in Dev Tools.

Solution: check 'Offline' checkbox at the network tab, which will fail to send the request, so the tab will not be closed.