# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() inside shopping cart ,

Tags: php

[image]
I am trying to get more than 1 item in my shopping cart array but I run into an issue

This is my database after inserting 1 item with post method

[image]
Items is defined in db as text

After trying to insert second product the items result gets overwritten.

My developers tools output after clicking add to cart

[image]

**ADD**

I am using add to cart button from my modal >https://pastebin.com/HKSRTG4L that is submitting via ajax and parsed to add-cart.php

Where I have add to cart function : https://pastebin.com/guv0rB6x

[image]

This is my code from cart.php :

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/EcomApp/konfiguracija.php";
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/config.php';

include 'include/head.php';
include 'include/izbornik.php';


if($cart_id != ''){
  $cartQ = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '$cart_id';");
  $cartQ->execute();
  $result= $cartQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);var_dump($items) ;
  $i = 1;
  $sub_total = 0;
  $item_count = 0;

}

?>

<div class="col-md-12">

  <div class="row">
<h2 class ="text-center">Your Shopping Cart </h2><hr>
<?php if($cart_id =='') :?>



  <div class="bg-danger">
   <p class="text-center text-danger">
     Your shopping cart is empty!
 </p>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
<table class="table" >
<thead><th>#</th><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Size</th><th>Sub Total</th></thead>
<tbody>

  <?php
  foreach ($items as $item){
        $product_id =$item['id'];
        $productQ = $veza ->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$product_id'");
        $productQ ->execute();
        $product= $productQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sArray = explode (',',$product['sizes']);
        foreach($sArray as $sizeString){
          $s = explode(':',$sizeString);
          if($s[0] ==$item['size']){
            $available = $s[1];
          }
        }
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?=$i;?></td>
            <td><?=$product['title'];?></td>
            <td><?=$product['price'];?></td>
            <td><?=$item['quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?=$item['size'];?></td>
            <td><?=$item['quantity'] * $product['price'];?></td>
            </t>
      <?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>

<?php include 'include/footer.php';?>
```

**I am 93% sure the problem is with array merge** since currently the insert is overwriting the row with new results and not adding to the array.

```
      <?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/konfiguracija.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/config.php';
$product_id = sanitize($_POST['product_id']);
$size = sanitize($_POST['size']);
$available = sanitize($_POST['available']);
$quantity = sanitize($_POST['quantity']);
$item = array();
$item[]= array(
  'id'        => $product_id,
  'size'      => $size,
  'quantity'  => $quantity,
);

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$query = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$product_id'");
$query ->execute();
$product = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['success_launch'] = $product['title']. 'was added to your cart.';

//check does cookie cart exist
if($cart_id != ''){
  $cartQ= $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '$cart_id'");
  $cart = $cartQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
  $item_match = 0;
  $new_items = array();
  foreach ($prevous_items as $pitem){
     if($item[0]['id']==$pitem['id'] && $item[0]['size'] == $pitem['size']){
       $pitem ['quantity']= $pitem['quantity']+$item[0]['quantity'];
       if ($pitem['quantity']>$available){
         $pitem['quantity'] = $available;

       }
       $item_match = 1;
     }
     $new_items[] = $pitem;
  }
  if($item_match != 1){
    $new_items = array_merge($item,(array)$previous_items);
  }
  $items_json = json_encode($new_items);
  $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));
  $something=$veza->prepare("UPDATE cart SET items = '$items_json',expire_date= '$cart_expire'WHERE id ='$cart_id'");
  $something ->execute();
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,'/',$domain,false);
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);

}else {
```

**INSERT**

```
//add cart inside database
  $items_json = json_encode($item);
  $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
  $smth=$veza->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('$items_json','$cart_expire')");

  $smth->execute();
  $cart_id = $veza->lastInsertId();

  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);

}
  var_dump($cart_id);

?>
```

**add to cart function** : https://pastebin.com/guv0rB6x

```
function add_to_cart(){
  jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");
  var size = jQuery('#size').val();
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
  var available = jQuery('#available').val();
  var error = '';
  var data = jQuery("#add_product_form").serialize();
  if(size == '' || quantity == '' || quantity == 0){
    error += '<p class= "bg-danger text-center">You must choose a size and quantity</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
    return;
  }else if (quantity>available){
    error += '<p class= "bg-danger text-center">There are only '+available+' available.</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
     return;
  }else{
    jQuery.ajax({
               url: '/EcomApp/admin/parsers/add_cart.php',
               method : 'post',
               data : data,
               success : function(){
                 location.reload();
               },
               error : function(){alert("Something went wrong");}

    });
  }
}
```

**konfiguracija.php** there is a (Undefined offset: 1)  on line 65

> $user_data['last'] = $fn[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIUKW.png);

but I think it is not directly connected to the functionality

```
try{
    $veza = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $veza->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $veza->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    $veza->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
}catch(PDOException $e){

    switch($e->getCode()){
        case 1049:
            header("location: " . $eone . "error/wrongDBname.html");
            exit;
            break;
        default:
            header("location: " . $eone . "error/error.php?code=" . $e->getCode());
            exit;
            break;
    }


}
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';
session_start();

//
$cart_id = '';
 if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){
     $cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
 }

if(isset($_SESSION['SDUser'])){
    $user_id =$_SESSION['SDUser'];
    $query = $veza->prepare("SELECT* FROM korisnik WHERE id ='$user_id'");
    $query->execute();
    $user_data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $fn = explode(' ', $user_data['full_name']);
    $user_data['first'] = $fn[0];
    $user_data['last'] = $fn[1];
     // print_r($user_data);

}

if(isset($_SESSION['success_launch'])){
    echo '<h1><p class="text-success">'.$_SESSION['success_launch'].'</p></h1>';
    unset($_SESSION['success_launch']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['error_launch'])){
    echo '<div class="success"><p class="text-success">'.$_SESSION['error_launch'].'</p></div>';
    unset($_SESSION['error_launch']);
}
```

Comment: Either `$items` not an array or empty

Comment: `$items` is not an array. Never assume that your query would always work flawlessly. Verify that it returned something before calling `json_decode()`

Comment: I am trying to transcribing mysqli way to pdo But I'm unable to found the solution with PDO, after trying to enter second product my database gets result items : NULL

Comment: I have updated my question because I think the problem is with mergin array, inside the add_cart.php

Comment: `$query = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$product_id'");` - where did you set value of parameter `product_id` ?

Comment: I should merge the array into one row inside the database and than grab it by its id, if you look at the database structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by casting the second argument of `array_merge` to an array:

```
$new_items = array_merge($item, (array)$previous_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

In add_cart.php:

```
$previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
$item_match = 0;
$new_items = array();
foreach ($prevous_items as $pitem){
```

Notice that `$previous_items` and `$prevous_items` are different.

That's why you're getting:

> Notice: Undefined variable: prevous_items in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcomApp/admin/parsers/add_cart.php on line 29

You didn't take my previous advice to make your life easier.

Apparently working code is not enough. Always validate and fail fast ( http://www.practical-programming.org/ppl/docs/articles/fail_fast_principle/fail_fast_principle.html ):

```
if(!$cart_id){
  $cartQ = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = ?");
  $cartQ->execute([(int)$cart_id]);
  $result= $cartQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if (!isset($result['items'])) {
      throw new \RuntimeException("The items were not found.");
  }
  $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
  if (!$items) {
      throw new \RuntimeException("Invalid items format.");
  }
  $i = 1;
  $sub_total = 0;
  $item_count = 0;
}
```

As said, do something like this:

```
<?php

$validKeys = ['product_id', 'size', 'available', 'quantity'];
foreach ($validKeys as $key) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$key])) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Parameter $key is missing.");
    }
}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/konfiguracija.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/EcomApp/config.php';

$product_id = sanitize($_POST['product_id']);
$size = sanitize($_POST['size']);
$available = sanitize($_POST['available']);
$quantity = sanitize($_POST['quantity']);
```

Most probably you missed something in the client side (javascript or HTML form), for instance, you might have misspelled "product_id".

**ADDED:**

https://pastebin.com/guv0rB6x

```
function add_to_cart(){
  jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");
  var size = jQuery('#size').val();
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
  var available = jQuery('#available').val();
  var error = '';
  var data = jQuery("#add_product_form").serialize();
  if(size == '' || quantity == '' || quantity == 0){
    error += '<p class= "bg-danger text-center">You must choose a size and quantity</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
    return;
  }else if (quantity>available){
    error += '<p class= "bg-danger text-center">There are only '+available+' available.</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
     return;
  }else{
    jQuery.ajax({
               url: '/EcomApp/admin/parsers/add_cart.php',
               method : 'post',
               data : data,
               success : function(){
                 location.reload();
               },
               error : function(){alert("Something went wrong");}

    });
  }
}
```

You're not checking if the "product_id" field is empty.

**ADDED:**

Replace:

```
  $previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
  $item_match = 0;
  $new_items = array();
  foreach ($prevous_items as $pitem){
     if($item[0]['id']==$pitem['id'] && $item[0]['size'] == $pitem['size']){
       $pitem ['quantity']= $pitem['quantity']+$item[0]['quantity'];
       if ($pitem['quantity']>$available){
         $pitem['quantity'] = $available;

       }
       $item_match = 1;
     }
     $new_items[] = $pitem;
  }
  if($item_match != 1){
    $new_items = array_merge($item,(array)$previous_items);
  }
```

With something like this:

```
$previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'], true);
if (!$previous_items) {
      $previous_items = array();
}
$items_by_unique = array();
foreach (array_merge($item, $previous_items) as $item) {
    if (!isset($item['id'], $item['size'], $item['quantity'])) {
      throw new RuntimeException('Found a invalid invalid data: ' . json_encode($item));
    }
    $unique = $item['id'] . '-' . $item['size'];
    if (isset($items_by_unique[$unique])) {
      $old_item = $items_by_unique[$unique];
      $item['quantity'] = $old_item['quantity'];
    }
    if ($item['quantity'] > $available) {
      $item['quantity'] = $available;
    }
    $items_by_unique[$unique] = $item;
}
$items_json = json_encode(array_values($items_by_unique));
```

Comment: I have tried using that json application process , but I got lost didn't know to use it to debug my post ? If I use your $validateKeys example instead I receive Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function RuntimeException() in  , in my config.php I have catch(PDOException $e){ switch($e->getCode()){ and than cases, but only for wrong database name errors... Here is my modal file : https://pastebin.com/HKSRTG4L , could it be again the path issue, I will look into all of the documentation you provided since I realize it is a better approach in debugging

Comment: I made a mistake. Missed "new": "throw new RuntimeException("Parameter $key is missing.");" Anyway, if you see that error, that means that you're not sending all the required data.

Comment: Uncaught RuntimeException: Parameter product_id is missing.

Comment: Probably the mistake is in the add_to_cart() javascript function, which I can't see.

Comment: I placed this fuction inside the footer : https://pastebin.com/guv0rB6x

Comment: Update your question adding those URLs.

Comment: I am getting Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcomApp/cart.php on line 41 , and without being able to overwrite the item in cart anymore

Comment: okay that is because I am throwing that exception. Okay I will edit my question , sorry for not providing all the data

Comment: I have added my dev out to the question , it is returning product id

Comment: With your error handling method I have found out that : Notice: Undefined variable: items in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcomApp/cart.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcomApp/cart.php on line 46, where I have   foreach ($items as $item) set

Comment: Did you validate $items?

Comment: Well I am not sure how , items is in my example multidimensional associative array

Comment: If I use your error handling replace I am outputting items : null to database

Comment: I think parsing it to array removes the issue, but it is still undefined variable items ?

Comment: What I am guessing is that it is the merge_array problem, as it with my code after casting to array I am able to overwrite that cart item, but inside the database it should just add it under items like so: [{"id":"1","size":"Small","quantity":"2"},{"id":"15","size":"9","Large":"3"}]

Comment: Add the database definition. If it's a small VARCHAR, it will be truncated.

Comment: items is defined as text

Comment: Well I am not sure about this but there is a previous bug in Notice: Undefined offset: 1 inside configuration.php, and by applying fail fast way means I should't even be letting my application come to this part. But I think they are not directly connected

Comment: It's better to have an issue per Stackoverflow question otherwise the answers and comments become too confuse. I edited the answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168052/discussion-between-lortnok-and-pedro-amaral-couto).

Answer (score 0):

The code has lots of issues that make very hard to find the mistakes and it's very hard to answer a question which is really several questions which are always increasing, as if we're making a debugging service for free... We could be discussing here for several hours and days, like a job, until everything is corrected. In that case, it's going to be very hard to help and take care of our personal lives and jobs.

Anyway, I'm going to enumerate some issues that make the code very hard to debug.

Most of the returned values are not validated, assuming that they're what's expected, instead failing immediately when there's an error. That means that you may only notice there's a mistake a lot later and hunt for the its source, which might be in a different file.

For instance, when you do something like this:

```
$query = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$product_id'");
$query->execute();
$product = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You should always check if `$product` is at least not empty:

```
if (!$product) {
    throw new RuntimeException("The product #$product_id" was not found.");
}
```

Also, putting variables inside SQL statements can be very dangerous. If you're using prepared statements you should do something like this:

```
$query = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$query->execute([$product_id]);
```

The code does not take advantage of reusability. You can implement classes or functions and test them independently.

For instance, you could have done something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Add a new item ...
 * 
 * If it's being requested more items then available ...
 *
 * @param array $newItem The new item that should be added.
 * @param array $items The list of items where the item should be added.
 * @param integer $available Available items.
 * @return void
 */
function add_item(array $newItem, array &$items, int $available=MAX_INT_MAX)
{
  throw_error_if_invalid_item($newItem);

  $unique = $newItem['id'] . '-' . $newItem['size'];
  if (isset($items_by_unique[$unique])) {
    add_item_quantity(
      $items_by_unique[$unique],
      $item['quantity'],
      $available
    );
  } else {
    $items[] = $newItem;
  }
}

/**
 * Add quantity ...
 *
 * @param array $item ...
 * @param integer $moreQuantity ...
 * @param integer $available ...
 * @return void
 */
function add_item_quantity(array &$item, int $moreQuantity, int $available=MAX_INT_MAX)
{
  $item['quantity'] += $moreQuantity;
  if ($item['quantity'] > $available) {
    $item['quantity'] = $available;
  }
}

/**
 * ...
 *
 * @param array $item ...
 * @return void
 */
function throw_error_if_invalid_item(array $item)
{
  if (!isset($item['id'], $item['size'], $item['quantity'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
      'Found a invalid invalid item data: ' . json_encode($item)
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can make individual test in isolated files:

```
<?php
$item = array(
  'id' => 10,
  'size' => 'm',
  'quantity' => 2,
);
add_item_quantity($item, 3, 10);
if ($item['quantity'] != 5) {
   echo "wrong! quantity = {$item['quantity']}\n";
} else {
  echo "correct!\n";
}
```

If you put your classes or functions in dedicated files, you can reuse them as a library making the code easy to read, testable and secure:

```
<?php
throw_error_if_invalid_item($_POST);
$newItem = create_item($_POST);
$items = fetch_cart_items($cart_id);
add_item($newItem, $items, 10);
save_cart_items($items);
show_json_items($json);
```

With classes it would be much easier (eg: you wouldn't have to worry about missing array keys) and you could use [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) to test all the functions and methods automatically. Check how I did that for a simple project:

https://github.com/pedroac/nonce4php

You can also make any error or warning halt the script:

```
<?php
set_error_handler(
    function (int $errno , string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "ERROR #$errono:$errfile:$errline: $errstr";
        die();
    }
);

set_exception_handler(
    function (Throwable $exception) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo $exception->getMessage();
        die();
    }
);
```

If you follow the [good practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/), it will be much easier to found mistakes and let others help you.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. I have learned a lot and I will use this approach for my future projects