# How to determine date format for php curl?

Tags: php, curl, datepicker

I have a simple script that curls into a site to get flight information.  The site has input for departure city, arrival city, and date.  The date field on the actual site uses datepicker with a placeholder format as mm/dd/yyyy, and when a date is selected with date picker the date input field populates with something like 04/14/2019.

My script includes:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.somesite.com");

$curl_data = "dep=YYY&arr=ZZZ&date=04/14/2019";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I echo the output, it always tell me that I submitted an invalid date.  I've tried multiple formats.  Any ideas on how to determine the proper date format or what else I might need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Submit the form in your browser and see what format the browser sends the data in. Also a lot of datepickers actually have two inputs boxes overlapping to achieve the datepicker functionality. Check the DOM to make sure you don't have a hidden input named `date1` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form on the real site you can check the POST data with the web developers console: [How can I debug a HTTP POST in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome)

Comment: Did what your link suggested and I got the following for the date: 02/21/2019.  When viewing source or url encoded it had 02%2F21%2F2019. I tried that but still not working.

Comment: `%2F` is a `/` character - see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Try it with the `/` character.

Comment: I’ve tried that as well.  I think the page I’m submitting actually redirects to a second page so I’ll take the output from page 1 and try to curl into page 2 tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: You can enable [autoredirect](https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/) in curl.

Comment: Thomas... I enabled redirect this morning and that did the trick.  Thanks.