# Unable to log in a site using payload with appropriate parameters as it doesn't show up in chrome dev tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to log in ***[this website](https://member.angieslist.com/member/login)*** using my credentials running python script but the problem is that the xhr requests visible as `login` in chrome dev tools stays for a moment and then vanishes, so I can't see the appropriate parameters (supposed to be recorded) necessary to log in. However, I do find that `login` in xhr if I put my password wrong. The form then looks incomplete, though.

I've tried so far (an incomplete payload because of chrome dev tools):

```
import requests

url = "https://member.angieslist.com/gateway/platform/v1/session/login"

payload = {"identifier":"username","token":"sometoken"}

res = requests.post(url,json=payload,headers={
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0",
    "Referer":"https://member.angieslist.com/member/login"
    })
print(res.url)
```

***How can I log in that site filling in appropriate parameters issuing a post http requests?***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome Tried this?

Comment: This specific case is unusual and the records are not visible in xhr requests within network tab in chrome dev tools @Jammy Dodger .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox called *Persist logs* in the Network tab and if its switched on the data about the post request remains. I think you should requests a session if you need to keep the script logged in. It may be done with:

```
import requests
url = 'https://member.angieslist.com/gateway/platform/v1/session/login'
s = requests.session()
payload = {"identifier":"youremail","token":"your password"}
res = s.post(url,json=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0",'Referer': 'https://member.angieslist.com/member/login?redirect=%2Fapp%2Faccount'}).text
print(res)
```

the post requests returns a json file with all details of user.

Comment: In my case it is ***Preserve log***. It's an invaluable piece of information.

Comment: oh yeah I was using Firefox