# Laravel - AJAX file upload returning null

Tags: ajax, laravel

This is my ajax request:

```
var files = $('#imgur_attach')[0].files;

  if(files.length > 0){
    var fd = new FormData();
    
    // Append data 
    fd.append('file',files[0]);
    fd.append('_token',$globalToken);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: host + "/attach-comment-image/" ,
        data: {fd},
```

Controller:

```
public function attach(Request $request) {
    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'image|required',
    ]);
```

When sending this ajax request, the validator tells me that the "file" field is required. Trying to return `request->get('file')` returns `null`.

However, when I do `console.log(fd);` before the ajax request, it returns the following:
[image]

Why is this happening? I don't normally upload files with AJAX over a regular POST request, so I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: what's is in AJAX's payload?

Comment: In the console.log(fd) you already see, that `file -> {}`, so it isn't filled. In your `fd.append('file',files[0]);`, see if you get something from `files[0]`, this is purely debugging. What is in `var files`, for example?

Comment: @UnderDog console.log(files); returns the following: FileList [ File ]
​
0: File { name: "Untitled.png", lastModified: 1672461379071, size: 17639, … }
​
length: 1

Comment: @AliRaza how can I show you the payload?

Comment: Using the network tab in dev tools for your browser:
e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome

Comment: @AliRaza the payload part just says [object Object]. Strange.

Comment: What does `$request->files()->all()` return?

Answer (score 1):

Try stringify data before sending like this:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {fd: JSON.stringify(fd),
  ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Request payload is still just [object Object]. I also tried removing processData: false, since you're stringifying but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add multipart form data

```
contentType: "multipart/form-data",
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the input around with a form tag like this did the trick:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Not sure why setting `contentType: "multipart/form-data"` in the ajax request doesn't work, but this solution works so I'll just use this instead.